printers with python GUI
print files with Windows 11 with Python using GUI, to select printers and printer trays, as shown in the image.
The printer I use is a RICHO im430.
I currently generate pdf files and after reading them all and printing the code I use is as follows:
def Imprimi_nova(self):
        lista_impressora = win32print.EnumPrinters(2)# Lista de impressoras no PC
        #for impressora in lista_impressora:
            #print(f'Lista a impressora {impressora}')#indice 0 da impressora
        myImpressora = lista_impressora[0]
       
        ### Adicionado para pagar a bandeja manual
        handle = win32print.OpenPrinter(myImpressora[2])
        
        
        #property = win32print.GetPrinter(handle, 2) #Usualmente '2' é a bandeja manual
        #property['pDevMode'].__dict__['BinSelection'] = 2
        #print(property['pDevMode'])
        #property['pDevMode'].BinSelection = 2

        #win32print.SetPrinter(handle, 2, property, 0)
        #win32print.ClosePrinter(handle) #Fecha a configuração
        ### Fim da bandeja manual


        win32print.SetDefaultPrinter(myImpressora[2])

        #seta a pasta e impressão
        caminho = r"\\10.40.22.35\Plantão\Para Impressão do termo de recebimento\Imprimir"
        #print(caminho)
        lista_arq_print = os.listdir(caminho)
        
        for arquivo in lista_arq_print:
            pass
            #print("Remover este e habilitar a linha abaixo para imprimir")
            win32api.ShellExecute(0, "print", arquivo, None, caminho, 0)
            #print(f'o caminho é: {caminho} \n Os arquivo excluidos serão: {arquivo}')
            os.remove(os.path.join(caminho, arquivo))# Remove após a impressão
    ### FIM ### def Imprimi_nova(self):

I tried the following code:
    ### Adicionado para pagar a bandeja manual
        handle = win32print.OpenPrinter(myImpressora[2])
        
        property = win32print.GetPrinter(handle, 2) #Usualmente '2' é a bandeja manual
        property['pDevMode'].__dict__['BinSelection'] = 2
        print(property['pDevMode'])
        property['pDevMode'].BinSelection = 2

        win32print.SetPrinter(handle, 2, property, 0)
        win32print.ClosePrinter(handle) #Fecha a configuração
        ### Fim da bandeja manual

I changed the (property), and it doesn't have it, I didn't find anything in the PCL6 driver or in the im430 manual.

Welcome to StackOverflow!
What exactly is the question or the problem you're having? Which property did you change? What doesn't have what?
